# Rails 3, mail and OpenSSL problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, sendmail, passenger

I keep getting this error in my production enviroment

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname was not match with the server certificate)`

I really don't know much about certificates. I have configured rails to use sendmail. Sendmail is working well in other php applications on the server. 
I use Phusion Passenger.
I also have a redmine-app which uses sendmail and also works fine (but it runs rails 2.x)
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means the SSL Certificate installed on the mail server did not match its hostname.

You can disable these exceptions, but then you are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

The other option is to get a proper SSL Certificate (or install it correctly) for your mail server.

For more on SSL Certs I suggest superuser.com